# return info of unsubscribed mobile operator

Tags: android, telephony

how can I access the information of various network operators on my device using android?
such as basestation id, cell id and signal strength?

same problem here:
[Change the Network Operator with an Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976440/change-the-network-operator-with-an-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) is what you want..But I am not sure whether it gives signal strength info..[This](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/06/get-network-info-using-telephonymanager.html) blog post might be useful too

Comment: HI, I already checked TelephonyManager and it only returns info on the subscribed network. Actually my goal is to have the info on all available network operators...Thanks for the help